# ggplot images not appearing in .md github_documents

Tags: r, knitr, github-document

I recently parameterized hundreds of reports. The html_documents look great, but in the .md reports, which are github_documents, the images are not appearing.

.md file viewed in GitHub:
[image]

Same .md file in raw format:
[image]

The images have successfully pushed to GitHub:
[image]

Why aren't my image files mapping to my reports?

Comment: Are those file paths hard coded into the `.md`? Best guess is that `/Users/jpowers4/Documents/...` is not a relative path. If you are using `knitr` check out the `output: github_document` option to create `.md` files from `.rmd` files. https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/github_document_format.html

Comment: @nniloc, so if I manually update the path to drop the absolute section, the images display. I wonder why generating the .md files from a parameterized for-loop resulted in absolute file paths.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more. Sounds like the file paths are programmatically generated in the loop. Maybe the loop is using `list.files(full.names = TRUE)`?

Comment: @nniloc, actually that was close to the issue. I was specifying paths using here::here(), which was providing the absolute paths. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in how I specified the location of my output files in the render() function within my for loop.

This loop specified absolute file paths and in turn the image file locations were also being specified with absolute file paths.

```
dir_datasets <- here::here('data', 'cooked', 'gamma_a4_b0-04')

mdes <- c(.980, .990, .995, 1.010, 1.020, 1.030)
mdes_str <- broman::myround(mdes, 3)
my_files <- list.files(dir_datasets)

for (mde in mdes) {
    for (file in my_files){
        TRUE_EFFECT <- extract_string_from_filename(file, 3)
        MDE_TITLE <- dash4dot(mde, 3)

        rmarkdown::render(
            fs::path(dir_sprt_ttest, 'template.Rmd'),
            output_file = fs::path(
                dir_output, paste0('tte', TRUE_EFFECT, '_mde', MDE_TITLE, '.md')
                ),
            params = list(file_name = file, mde = mde)
        )
    }
}
```

When I remove the absolute filepath from the `output_file` argument in `render()` the images were thereafter saved with relative filepaths, too, and the .md files displayed their images after being pushed to GitHub.

```
output_file = paste0('tte', TRUE_EFFECT, '_mde', MDE_TITLE, '.md') # note that I dropped fs::path(dir_output,
```